# "m'en allant promener..."

Tags: expressions, pronoms, paroles-de-chanson, gérondif

Quand j'étais petite fille, ma mère (une Canadienne) me chantait des chansons en français. Je les ai chantées à mes enfants du mieux que je me souvenais, mais pour la plupart je les ai depuis oubliées.

Maintenant que j'ai une jeune petite-fille, j'essaie de réapprendre ces chansons pour pouvoir les lui chanter comme ma mère me l'a fait.

Deux lignes de "À la claire fontaine" me confondent (ce qui n'est pas difficile ! J'ai beaucoup oublié).

Dans les lignes :

> À la claire fontaine *m'en allant promener*
>   J'ai trouvé l'eau si belle que je *m'y* suis baigné

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi la phrase *m'en allant promener* est construite de cette façon. Peut-être que je ne la comprends pas. Je penserais que ça devrait être "en m'en allant promener..."

Aussi, je ne comprends pas pourquoi "je *m'y* suis baigné" n'est pas rendu "je *me* suis baigné".

S'agit-il des expressions familières ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur ce StackExchange ! Vos contributions autre part sont si fantastiques. :) Vous pouvez voir mes corrections en lisant l'histoire des révisions. Si vous voudriez des explications ou plus de détails signalez-le-moi.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - Merci pour l'accueil chaleureux (?). :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak - Me chantait = sang to me; me chanterait = ? would sing (to) me? Aussi, oui, la chanson n'est pas difficile, mais je veut dire que ce n'est pas difficile de me confonder. :)

Comment: Oh, lol ! Corrigé. Oui, « chaleureux ». For "chanterait", English "would" is only translated by conditionnel when it's hypothetical. If you mean "she would sing to me" as in "she often sang to me", that's imparfait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est tout le contraire de famillier. *À la Claire Fontraine" est une chanson du tout début du XVIIe siècle et comprend plusieurs éléments de syntaxe qui sont aujourd'hui disparus ou limité à la littérature.

C'est le de "m'en allant promener". D'une part il présente un gérondif (=/= le *gerund* anglais) sans *en*, ce qui était très commun autrefois mais largement limité à l'expression littéraire, ou, dans la langue de tous les jours, à des expressions figées comme "chemin faisant".

D'autre part, la chanson utilise "promener" là où la langue moderne utiliserait généralement "se promener".

Une reformulation plus moderne serait donc "En m'en allant me promener" ou "En allant me promener".

Pour ce qui est de "Je m'y suis baigné", le pronom *y* se réfère à un complément locatif, ici "l'eau si belle" dans la première partie du vers.

> J'ai trouvé l'eau si belle que je me suis baigné [dans cette eau]
>
> J'ai trouvé l'eau si belle que je m'y suis baigné

Là encore il s'agit d'une tournure de phrase qui est devenue plus rare dans la langue familière, où *y* est concurencé par *là* et d'autre adverbes locatifs dans cet usage. La forme moderne familière serait "J'ai trouvé l'eau tellement belle que je me suis baigné dedans".

Comment: Merci Beaucoups! Oui, si c'etait moi, je dirais, "je me suis baigné dedans". C'est intéressant de réaliser à quel point je sais peu de choses sur ma langue maternelle.

Comment: @medica C'est une chanson, donc si une autre formulation donne le bon nombre de syllabes c'est elle qui sera retenue ^^

Comment: Pourriez-vous svp., à l'occasion d'une mise à jour éventuelle, utiliser un mot en plus du symbole (d'inégalité) =/= ? Merci !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - Compris! Nous avons le même problème en anglais.

Answer (score 5):

*(English follows if needed)*

L'emploi de *y* ici est plus facile à expliquer, donc je commencerai avec ça.

N'oubliez pas que « y » se traduit par « there, in that place, at that place ». Comparez donc :

> Je me suis baigné → I bathed/swam
>   
> Je m'**y** suis baigné → I bathed/swam **in it**

Pour *m'en allant promener*, cela renvoie à l'expression figée « s'en aller », qui veut dire « aller », plus ou moins — avec peut-être en peu plus de l'idée de « quitter » : "**Going off** on a walk."

Génial que vous chantez toujours ces chansons. :) Peut-être que celles que vous avez oubliées se trouvent sur cette page de « [chansons enfantines](http://www.chansons-net.com/index.php) » ?

P.S. Eau qui dort dans sa réponse note qu'en français moderne on dirait « me promener » au lieu de « promener ». Cela me gêne un peu parce que comme on voit [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/promener), la formulation du 17e siècle s'employait de la même façon !

Donc j'ai une autre solution à proposer : que cette phrase est l'équivalente de « en allant me promener » en français moderne. C'est possible vu que l'ordre des pronoms n'a pas toujours été figée, et diffère même dans d'autres langues romanes, comme l'espagnol ou le pronom précède le verbe modal. Peut-être que le français de cette époque faisait ainsi.

---

The use of "y" here is easier to explain, so I'll start with that.

Don't forget that « y » is translated "there, in that place, at that place". So compare:

> Je me suis baigné → I bathed/swam
>   
> Je m'**y** suis baigné → I bathed/swam **in it**

For *m'en allant promener*, that goes back to the expression « s'en aller », which means « aller », more or less — maybe with a little more of the idea of "leaving": "**Going off** on a walk."

Awesome that you're still singing these songs. :) Maybe the ones you've forgotten can be found on this page of "[songs for children](http://www.chansons-net.com/index.php)"?

P.S. Eau qui dort in his answer notes that in modern French you'd say "me promener" instead of "promener". That makes it a bit harder for me since as one can see [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/promener), the 16th-century formulation was used the same way!

So I have another solution to suggest: that this phrase is the equivalent of "en allant me promener" in modern French. This is possible given that the order of pronouns wasn't always fixed, and even differs in other Romance languages, such as Spanish where the pronoun precedes the modal verb. Maybe the French this era did likewise.

Comment: Merci beaucoups! C'est exactement ce que je voulais savoire! I understand "s'en aller" as you do, as in leaving (je vais m'en aller). Mais, c'est un peut plus difficile comprendre cette construsion.

Comment: re: la possibilité que le *me* soit l'objet de *promener* qui soit remonté sur *allant*, j'y ai effectivement pensé moi aussi, et ça aurait certainement été possible, mais le *en* du gérondif est d'origine prépositionnelle et il ne lui a jamais été possible (à ma connaissance) de s'intercaler entre des pronoms clitiques et leur verbe hôte. Ca aurait donc donné "En m'allant promener", ce qui n'est pas ce qu'on voit ici.

Comment: @Eauquidort Merci !