# Vous en souhaitant

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe, participe-présent, en

J'ai reçu un email comportant :

> Je vous prie de bien vouloir trouver en pièce jointe : le Procès
>   verbal du Conseil de l'UFR (...) du 12 février 2018. **Vous en
>   souhaitant bonne réception**.

Je sais que **en souhaitant** est le gérondif de souhaiter. Moi, j'attendais une structure comme : **En vous souhaitant bonne réception**.

D'où vient cette tournure avec la inversion (**vous en**) ?

Comment: À comparer avec « [m'en allant promener](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29484/men-allant-promener) » !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une formule toute faite assez courante et bien sûr correcte.

La formule la plus complète syntaxiquement parlant serait :

> En vous en souhaitant une bonne réception,...

mais elle est trop lourde à cause de la répétition des *en*. Le premier, celui du gérondif, est donc omis comme l'est aussi l'article *une*.

Dans tous les cas, la proposition introduite par le gérondif est équivalente à une subordonnée circonstancielle temporelle qui indique la simultanéité de l'action avec la principale. Un problème est que cette principale est souvent absente et seulement sous entendue.

Quand ce n'est pas le cas, la phrase complète peut être, par exemple :

> [Tout en] vous en souhaitant bonne réception, je vous prie d'agréer l'expression de mes salutations distinguées.

*En* fait référence à quelque chose qui doit être reçu avec le courrier ou indépendamment de celui-ci mais qui a été mentionné précédemment.

La phrase est donc équivalente à :

> En même temps que je vous souhaite (ou que nous vous souhaitons) une bonne réception de la chose en question,...

Comment: **En vous souhaitant bonne réception** est fausse syntaxiquement ? Si l'on veut parler avec précision, ladite formule courante **Vous en souhaitant bonne réception** n'est pas fausse syntaxiquement ? Je ne puis trouver une seule explication grammaticale.

Comment: **En vous souhaitant bonne réception** n'est pas fausse syntaxiquement à ma connaissance, de même pour **Vous en souhaitant bonne réception**. Cependant, je me heurte également à un manque d'explications grammaticales.

Comment: @jlliagre Vous en souhaitant n'est-elle pas la même structure syntaxique comme les expressions ce disant, ce faisant, etc. ?

Comment: Oui, *ce faisant* = *en faisant cela*

Answer (score 4):

Visiblement, "vous en souhaitant" est une **formulation plus courtoise** de "en vous souhaitant" <sup>[1](http://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/mail-professionnel-avec-piece-jointe-vous-en-souhaitant-bonne-reception/),[2](https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=90996&titre=Vous%20en%20souhaitant%20bonne%20r%E9ception), [3](http://forum.lefigaro.fr/forum/affich-10-vous-souhaitant-bonne-reception-ou-vous-en-souhaitant-bonne-reception)</sup> .

`Vous en souhaitant bonne réception` ne peut être écrit que lorsque la pièce jointe en question a été mentionnée en amont dans la correspondance.
Je ne saurais répondre quant à l'origine historique d'une telle formulation, mais `vous en souhaitant` est décrite (dans les liens donnés plus tôt dans ma réponse) comme la façon la plus élégante et la plus formelle de souhaiter quelque chose à quelqu'un.

Answer (score 3):

It may help to keep in mind that *en* doesn’t have the same grammatical function in those sentences: in one it is a preposition, in the other it is a pronoun:

*En vous souhaitant bonne reception*: wishing you prompt/safe delivery: here *en* is the preposition always going with the gérondif (*En passant, en chantant, en vous souhaitant joyeux Noël*).

*Vous en souhaitant bonne reception*: wishing you prompt/safe delivery OF IT/OF THEM. Here *en* is a pronoun. And the “*souhaitant*” is a *participe présent*.

Putting the full sentence of salutation, following a comma instead of a full stop, would make BOTH choices grammatically ok, because normally, you need a conjugated verb somewhere to make a sentence feel complete.

But as the other answers say, very often, that conjugated bit is part of the formalities, and nowadays just implied: those various “*je vous PRIE* (here is the conjugated bit) *d’agréer*” variations are just dropped.

Formal final sentences in French official correspondance used to be deliciously weird. It has simplified greatly, but you still see, at the end of letters, things like “*Veuillez agréer, cher Monsieur, l’expression de mes sincères pensées*” and other strangely obsolete looking phrases in that vein...
I personally never got the hang of all the protocol that governs it. I need to look it up check every time I write an official letter. Very codified! Your example shows the clever use of a gerund /participle followed by a full stop to just dodge the bullet!