# "T'en souhaitant"

Tags: usage, pronoms, locutions, syntaxe, gérondif

[Ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29775/vous-en-souhaitant) j'ai posé une question concernant la tournure *vous en souhaitant* comme dans la fin d'un courriel que j'avais reçu :

> Je vous prie de bien vouloir trouver en pièce jointe : le Procès
>   verbal du Conseil de l'UFR (...) du 12 février 2018. Vous en
>   souhaitant bonne réception.

On y a bien répondu et je sais maintenant que cette formule est courante, courtoise et correcte.

Ma question est simple : peut-on utiliser la version de tutoiement, à savoir, *t'en souhaitant* ou pas ? Est-elle considéré hors registre ?

Comment: "*La question a été [bien] répondue*" n'est pas correct, c'est probablement un anglicisme. *Répondre* est transitif **indirect**, on dit "*répondre **à** une question*", et pour pouvoir dire "*la question a été répondue*" il faudrait que le verbe soit transitif **direct**. Il faut dire quelque chose comme "*On a bien répondu/Ils ont bien répondu à la question*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat : On y a bien répondu est-ce correct ? (Merci pour le commentaire !)

Comment: Oui ! Par contre "*[citation] est-ce correct*" ne l'est pas ^^ *Est-ce* est déjà un groupe [sujet + verbe], on ne peut pas mettre un autre sujet. Au choix, : "*[citation] est-il correct ?*", "*Est-ce correct de dire [citation] ?*" ou "*[citation] : Est-ce correct ?*" (avec des guillemets autour de la citation si possible)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Très bien ! Merci de ton temps:-)!

Comment: "*est-ce*" est "*est-il*" sont parfois interchangeables (quand ils sont sujets de la phrase, comme "*Est-ce correct de .../Est-il correct de ...*"). Mais quand le sujet de la phrase est autre chose, il faut utiliser "*est-il*". J'espère que c'est pas trop confus !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat C'est noté:-)! Apprenant l'allemand actuellement, je réalise chaque jour que je fais des fautes en français que je ne les faisais pas auparavant...

Comment: *... des faute en français que **je ne faisais** pas auparavant*.

Comment: @jlliagre merci ; des faute**S**, non ?

Comment: oui bien sûr, une fôte d'inattention ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elle peut s'utiliser sans erreur parce que les sentiments exprimés par l'intermédiaire de la formule initiale ne comportent pas de connotations spéciales, telles que des connotations particulières de respect, comme de subalterne à supérieur, ou telles que des connotations de distance ; c'est une formule un peu passe partout qui ne confère que l'espoir de la bonne fin d'une procédure ; donc elle convient pour tout le monde et peut être utilisée à la seconde personne du singulier.

Answer (score 2):

C'est une formule un peu creuse qui sert à 'faire poli', et qui est donc plutôt superflue pour quelqu'un qu'on tutoie.

D'autre part, la formule --tout comme 'en vous remerciant (par avance)'-- incluant un participe présent, elle ne devrait pas *a priori* constituer une phrase à elle seule. Il est courant d'utiliser une virgule plutôt qu'un point puis de signer (une espèce d'ellipse).

Comment: Merci, cependant votre réponse contredit l'autre réponse reçue.

Comment: @dimitris Non, elle ne contredit pas ma réponse, et je suis parfaitement d'accord avec les questions de syntaxe mises en avant. Si je n'ai pas fait ces remarques moi-même, ce que je brulais d'envie de faire, ça n'a été que par le désir de ne pas soulever l'antagonisme habituel de ces gens qui changent tout, en particulier lorsqu'il n'y en a pas besoin, et qui savent tout mieux que tout le monde et à qui il ne faut rien dire sous peine de passer pour un sauvage.(champ 1)

Comment: @dimitris  J'ajouterai un détail ; oui, la formule peut paraitre un peu creuse, mais en y pensant bien, y en a-t-il une qui ne paraisse pas un peu creuse parmi toutes celles que l'on utilise  ? (fin)